# What is this x and how can I input it?

Tags: math-mode, characters

[image]

I don't know its name so I cannot search for it...

Comment: Looks like Chi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the letter x in calligraphic font I believe. In math mode, type `\mathcal{X}`. [image]

Just a little tip: If there are any symbols you are unsure of, give [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) a try. It allows you to draw out the symbol and the program will guess what it is you're trying to draw.

**EDIT:**
You can add a hat above it by typing `\hat{\mathcal{X}}`. Or `\widehat{\mathcal{X}}` as suggested in the comments.

[image]

Comment: Can I write it with a hat above it?

Comment: Yup certainly. See edit

Comment: Very good website, but it seems that I cannot visit it in China. Sad.

Comment: Better using `\widehat`.

Comment: @Bernard how is that "better"?

Comment: `\hat` is too small with capital letters, in my opinion.